# Does calling ObjectContext.SaveChanges() make the object size smaller?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a `class` level repository and inserting rows in some tables with populating their fields, I am doing this in a `for-loop` that has 10K items in it. So no where still I call `SaveChanges()`.
 I was thinking just call `SaveChanges()` one time at the end of `for-loop` and save them all at once.
But looks like in the middle of my program it is Running out of memory and crashes. I have 16GB of RAM and resource monitor shows 42% is being used.
So if I call `SaveChanges()` at the end of each item in the loop instead of at the end of the whole loop, does that make the size of it smaller and help with this memory issue?

Comment: Have you tried running the profiler to see if it does?  My guess is that it won't clear memory since it caches results, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Some code showing the general flow would be nice.

Comment: Also - is your database running on your local machine, or something else?  If it's running on your local machine, are you sure the DBMS isn't what's hogging all of the memory?  42% memory usage doesn't sound like enough to cause a crash, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that wouldn't save memory.
I would suggest after each iteration, call `SaveChanges()`, set the object to null and create a new one for next iteration so:

```
foreach(kitten)
{
  myRepo = new Repo();
  //....creating records
  myRepo.SaveChanges()
  myRepo = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1)Do NOT call SaveChanges() at the end of each iteration ,it is too slow
2)Check this
 [When should I call SaveChanges() when creating 1000's of Entity Framework objects? (like during an import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930982/when-should-i-call-savechanges-when-creating-1000s-of-entity-framework-object)
If you can use SqlBulkCopy ,it is very fast

Also check if your app is targeting x86 ,if it is you cannot access more than 2GB (actually it is less than that)

Comment: I have put it on "AnyCPU" . So it is x86?

Comment: Depends on your machine,more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934314/maximum-memory-a-net-process-can-allocate

and here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186256/net-out-of-memory-exception-used-1-3gb-but-have-16gb-installed